# better way to bind checkbox in a component to a table column in other component

Tags: angular

requirement link each checkbox in child component to a table column in parent component using intermediate service
current functionality each checkbox contain a two way binding
**what would be better to do** 
for example

```
        //child emplate
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="column_1">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="column_2">

//parent template
    <child #toggle></child> // child component selector
    <p-table >
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
           <tr>
              <th[hidden]="toggle.column_1">column_1</th>
              <th [hidden]="toggle.column_2">column_2</th>
           </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
          <td>
             <th [hidden]="toggle.column_1">{{rowData.column_1}}</th>
             <th [hidden]="toggle.column_2">{{rowData.column_2}}</th>
          </td>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For smaller use cases this approach is valid, for [example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/sorting/) if you simply want to toggle a couple of different settings on your table.

But in this case it is not very flexible since any changes to your column layout within the parent component would have to be reflected in the child component. This kind of tight coupling should be avoided.

A better solution would be to pass an array of column definitions to the child component (*column-chooser*). The column-chooser component then renders a checkbox for each item dynamically and then either exposes a method which accepts a column identifier and returns a boolean describing the visibility of that particular column or **even better** uses an @Ouput which emits an array of currently selected columns.

From what I am reading you are trying to toggle columns in your [PrimeNG Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) using checkboxes. A solution to your problem is actually described [in the PrimeNG Table documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/coltoggle).

As is standard for PrimeNG it utilizes [Angular structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) and in this case their own [MultiSelect component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) which adds and removes column definitions from an array that it shares with the table component. The table component then only renders columns contained in that array.

Instead of describing the code in detail here I have created a demo based on the documenation code.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52972303-primeng-table-column-toggle)**